# KnockoutJS Custom Databind to add mobile styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

After a lot of help yesterday, I've taken the demo cart example, and applied it to my app (a search for B&B rooms).

The idea is, you select from (1) Room Type - this then populates (2) Occupants - when you then select from (2) Occupants, it populates (3) Number Reqd

[image: Screen Shot]
The problem is I can't get it to add the mobile styling to the newly added drop down list, once the number of occupants has been selected: 
[image: Screen Shot 2]

There is a working fiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/g8cQz/5/

With help from @Dan - he got the styling to be applied to the Occupants dropdown, by adding `jqmOptions: sampleProductCategories`:

```
     <td>
        <select data-bind='jqmOptions: sampleProductCategories, options: $root.RoomCategories, optionsText: "TypeName", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: category'></select>
     </td>

     <td data-bind="with: category">
          <select data-bind='jqmOptions: sampleProductCategories, options: Occs, optionsText: "occdesc2", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.occupancy'></select> 
     </td>

      <td class='quantity' data-bind="with: category">
          <select data-bind="visible: $parent.occupancy, options: ko.utils.range(0, TypeCount), value: $parent.quantity"></select>
      </td>

ko.bindingHandlers.jqmOptions = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    $(element).selectmenu();
    $(element).selectmenu("refresh", true);
   }
  };
```

What do I need to add to get the Number Required dropdown list or Occupants dropdown list, to add styling to the number reqd, when Occupants is selected?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Move the initial jQuery mobile select to the init method, also use the applyBindingsToNode instead of manually calling update on the options binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmOptions = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { options: valueAccessor() }, context);
        $(element).selectmenu();
    },    
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        $(element).selectmenu("refresh", true);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @Anders - thank you - I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/g8cQz/6/ but it now shows the number reqd before the occupants has been selected - and it also changes the initial drop down of Occupants and number required to [Object: Object] - thanks, Mark